# Aligning Columns of Table in Kable/Knitr

Tags: r, kable

I am trying to make a basic table of means and standard deviations for a few variables, but I am having issues with alignment that I can't seem to figure out. I am using R Markdown to create the table. Here is an example of how I'm coding it with the  mtcars dataset.

```
mtcars %>%
  select(mpg, disp, wt) %>%
  stargazer(type = 'text',
            summary.stat = c("mean", "sd")) %>%
  kable() %>%
  kable_styling("striped", "hover", full_width=T)
```

In R Markdown, the table ends up appearing with all of the numbers in the columns all squished together. I have tried using align = 'c' in the kable() function, but it does not change how my columns align.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The `stargazer` function is outputting a character vector, not a dataframe. `kable` and `kable_styling` are not going to be able to do anything with that output, you need some other way of creating a dataframe with the summary statistics in it, which you can then pass to `kable`.

Comment: I looked at just using stargazer which gave me a nicer result with the following ```mtcars %>%
  select(mpg, disp, wt) %>%
  stargazer(type = "html", style = "aer",
          summary.stat = c("mean", "sd"), 
          title = "Summary Statistics")``` Yet the values for one row still seem slightly squished.